# ASP.NET MVC Set texts in the View or in the Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

What is the best practice in MVC (for testing, SOC and scaffolding) for setting texts (for exemple page title, h1,h2..)

Is it better to do it in the controlle, fill a viewmodel and send it to the view 
or directly typing texts in the view?

Also I will propably use ressouces files for global texts (like button text, menu texts) and local ressouces for view specific texts.

Answer (score 0):

The view is merely to present the output to the user. Depending on your requirement you can either:

1) Type the text in the view directly `<h2>Hello World</h2>` (for static content that will not change)

The latter two options are for ideal for dynamic content, where the content could be received from a database or some additional input.

2) Use the ViewBag to pass information to the view (in which case you would set it in the controller ie. `ViewBag.HelloWorld = "Hello World"` : `<h2>@ViewBag.HelloWorld</h2>`

3) Use a model to pass the information to your view. This should be your preferred option where possible. In your specific case you could use the controller to retrieve the content from your global resources, bind it to the model and pass it to the view.

The logic on where to get the data should come from the controller and the View's function should be to merely display it.

Comment: Thanks. This is very informative. Regarding your option 3, how to pass information from model to view.can you please post some code to get clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend binding properties on the viewModel to the UI.
This is not only more testable, but it's also more flexible. It makes it easier to implement features like mult language support etc.
I recommend avoiding hard coding text in the markup if you can